# Git freeze after total

Tags: linux, git, connection, freeze, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem with git server. I created git server on virtual Linux Debian 9 (Digital Ocean) with [the tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) (with one simple change my git is in directory `/home/git/project` without folder endings name .git) I created an `apache2` server with `php7.0` and `proftpd` server too, but that works fine. And now I can connect to the server with SourceTree on my Windows 10, and I can clone, but when I want to push it will freeze on line Total. I haven't any large files to push only one documentation of my game in .doc, it's less than 3MB. I waited all night, but it's not working here terminal output:

```
$ git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master 
Pushing to git@255.255.255.255:/home/git/project ///////It's changed to fake IP 
git@255.255.255.255's password:
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 55.27 KiB | 1.73 MiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Comment: For what it's worth—not much—the output shows that all the *objects* have gone to the server. At this point what the client (doing the push) sends to the server is the set of reference name changes to make: in this case, that's any new tags, and the new value the client wants the server to set for the server's `refs/heads/master`. If you have any pre-receive, update, or post-receive hooks, they could be holding everything up, perhaps.

Comment: folder `refs/heads/` is empty :-(

Comment: but `.git/refs/heads/master` is a huge number in hex

Comment: References are always (currently) 40-character-long hex numbers, which are the commit or other Git object to which that reference points. (Branch names always point to commit objects. Tags often point to annotated tag objects, and both tag and replacement references can point to any object at all.) So that's also normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what I did wrong. Folder was created by root and a didn't give permission to git user. So he could read files but not save and replace. Use chmod or delete git and create by git user with temporary normal shell. To me second option work petty well.