# Git push stuck after total line

Tags: git, github

Git push stopped responding after the total line. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

[image: Git push stuck]

Comment: At this point, *your side* of the operation is done: Git has sent, to GitHub, all the commits and the update request. Your software is now waiting for GitHub to acknowledge that they have completed the request (or to send back a rejection of the request). There's nothing for you to do but wait. If the wait times out, something has gone wrong between your computer and the computers at GitHub.

Comment: In the future, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Even though everything has been read locally and sent to GitHub, Git still have to update your local repository with the new state (to reflect what has been sent to the remote repository)

Check as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936758/6309) if there is any file right issue (chown/chmod), like a repository created as root, but used and pushed as a regular user.